# Mysql Update Firing Too Early with Jquery Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a countdown timer that is supposed to fire a function when it's done counting which I have loaded a php page with. The problem is that the timer function executes the php update before the timer is done counting down. If i wanted to update the mysql ONLY when the timer is done, is there a better way to do this? Ive tried ajax but it becomes problematic.

```
$('#timerinsert').countdown(plustime)
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
})
.on('finish.countdown',function(event) {
    $(this).html("<?php include "timerdone.php"; ?>");
});
```

The PHP:

```
    $thegamesql = "UPDATE MYSQL FUNCTION GOES HERE";
mysql_query($thegamesql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Definitely cant do it that way.. The php file will be included right away on page load and fire the update query. Does the finish.countdown actually fire when it's supposed to? Why did the ajax approach not work? Do you have a sample of your attempt?

Comment: try in [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) in php fie for delay

Comment: ajax was causing timeout errors and crashing my browser, as I have a countdown timer that required me to have a setInterval/setTimeout of 1000ms for the timer to function correctly, this was sending too many requests to the server and crashing things. I restructured all of my scripts to utilize javascript instead, but I still require that I access a DB, so here lies my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pending that your finish.countdown function fires properly, there's no reason that this shouldn't work for ya..

```
$('#timerinsert').countdown(plustime)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
    })
    .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'timerdone.php'
        }).done(function(html) {
            $(this).html(html);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I had high hopes this would work, but it just freezes the timer at 00:01 and nothing happens, checked the DB and the UPDATE does not fire.

Comment: This will work.. There must be something else going on.. Try adding "alert('test'); to the "finish.coundown" function and see if that fires.. that'll tell us the issue is within your ajax call. also do you see any console errors? is the path to your timerdone.php correct?

Comment: the alert works. no console errors. path is correct. I tried adding simply: 
    <?php echo "THIS WORKS"; ?> and nothing else to the timerdone.php but that isnt displaying.

Comment: does simply "$(this).html('THIS WORKS');" in the finish work?

Comment: Yes, it displays in the proper div.

Comment: well the issue is right there somewhere with your ajax response. what does the console say the response is? is it a successful request? also what version of jquery are you using?